# Parsing Error when using the Event Class wrapper to Prevent Live Data from Being Triggered More Than Once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am using the following class to prevent live data from being triggered more than once.

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
    private set


    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) null else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Usage example:

```
private val _mutableLogin = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Event<FTLogin>>("_mutableLogin")
    val loginLiveData: LiveData<Event<FTLogin>> = _mutableLogin
sealed class FTLogin: Parcelable  {
    @Parcelize
    data class UsernameEmpty(val show: Boolean): FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class PasswordEmpty(val show: Boolean): FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class Success(val model: String) : FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class Failure(val errorCase: Int, val errorMessage: String) : FTLogin()
}
```

i noticed that as soon as i press the home button, i get a crash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.Event@cc60464
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1897)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1104)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1844)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
```

How can i fix this error? i tried adding Parcelable on the event class but received a build error
non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Event is not parcelable and it should not be. I'm guessing there is no real reason to get the `LiveData<Event` from the SavedStateHandle. Personally I'd use https://github.com/Zhuinden/live-event for the one-off events anyway, but i am biased on that

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the SingleLiveEvent class to solve the issue

```
/**
 * A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after subscription, used for events like
 * navigation and Snackbar messages.
 *
 *
 * This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change (like rotation) an update
 * can be emitted if the observer is active. This LiveData only calls the observable if there's an
 * explicit call to setValue() or call().
 *
 *
 * Note that only one observer is going to be notified of changes.
 */
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)
    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }
        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        pending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }
    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }
    companion object {
        private val TAG = "SingleLiveEvent"
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    val loginLiveData =  SingleLiveEvent<FTLogin>()
sealed class FTLogin: Parcelable  {
    @Parcelize
    data class UsernameEmpty(val show: Boolean): FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class PasswordEmpty(val show: Boolean): FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class Success(val model: String) : FTLogin()
    @Parcelize
    data class Failure(val errorCase: Int, val errorMessage: String) : FTLogin()
}
```